# How do I import a .ttf file into my Visual Studio 2017 web project to be used as a CSS font-family value?

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio-2017, font-face

I've got a C# .NET application I'm developing in Visual Studio 2017. I'm trying to import a new font from a .ttf file. I place the file at assets/fonts/Futura.ttf. Then I try to import it with CSS like this:

```
@section Styles {
<style>
...

        @font-face {
          font-family: "Futura";
          src:  url("assets/fonts/Futura.ttf") format("TrueType"),
        }

...
</style>
}
```

But I get an error on the page that says:

```
error CS0103: The name 'font' does not exist in the current context
```

The problem line is where it says: @font-face {

Does anybody know why it doesn't understand @font-face? It's just a .cshtml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following cshtml code to use a new font from the ttf file.

Please add two '@' before font-face.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @@font-face {
            font-family: "Font Name";
            src: url("../fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf");
        }
    .testfont { font-family: 'Font Name'; }

    </style>

    <title>test111</title>
</head>
<body>
    <P class="testfont" >Hello, world</P>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]